# App Crashed onCreate Drawer Activity on Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android

Here is logCat for Error. Remember this problems occurs after android studio update to 3.0

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dogarsoft.matrialdesignpractice, PID: 28316
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dogarsoft.matrialdesignpractice/com.dogarsoft.matrialdesignpractice.ActivityHome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: To know the exact exception, Add try-catch block and try to run. You might be compiling something which is not there on XML file.

Comment: there is a problem with your layout, or with other part of your code.

Comment: Provide more code, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Check line 18 of the layout file you are inflating with setContentView in your ActivityHome

Comment: xml code for fregment starts from line #18 but cannot tract error. Below is code from line #18
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.dogarsoft.matrialdesignpractice.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/drawer_activity_home" />